# What is the difference between setMap and setPath?

Tags: google-maps, google-polyline

I'm starter.

Look at this:

```
poly = new google.maps.Polyline({map: map});
poly.setOptions({strokeColor: 'blue', strokeOpacity: 0.5, strokeWeight: 4});
poly.setPath(path);
```

This code draw a polyline for me. But as I know, we have to draw by setMap(map).
So what is the difference between setMap and setPath?
Thank you.

Comment: My problem is that I can't remove polylines by setMap(null).

Comment: we need more context, the posted code as it is is correct and should work fine with `poly.setMap(null);`

Comment: Yes Dr. By poly.setMap(null) I can just hide it. But I want to remove it completely. Something like: poly.setPath(null); I don't know but setMap(null) doesn't work.